Why do I get User-Unhandled exception?
As far as I know if await Task.Run, then I can catch the exception. But why Visual Studio throws unhandled exception? How to avoid this and let the try/catch handle exception inside Task.Run?


Does it go into the catch if you step on?

@Fildor Yes it does. But I don't want the program to stop there every time exception happens.

Review the "Exception Settings". I think you may want to untick that option.

I'd just backup the VS configuration and then restore the "Exception Settings" to default and proceed from there.

You should un-tick the "Break when this exception type is user-unhandled" option, as the catch is outside the Task function, and make sure it stays so.
Alternatively you could try moving the try-catch block inside the task function and see if it then recognizes it as "user-handled".
